# Why does monkeypatch not recognize an assignment value in the constructor?

Tags: python, tdd, pytest

I'm practicing *TDD* and I'm fairly new at this. In my test case, I want to read from **stdin** and check if the output matches the input.

For **stdin** I'd like to use a mock object. Therefore I used `monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', StringIO(string))` to replace **stdin** with **StringIO**, because both have the method `read()`.

```py
# XPath.py
import sys
from io import StringIO

class XPath:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin = sys.stdin

    def readStdin(self):
        return self.stdin.read()
```

```py
# TestXPath.py
import pytest
from XPath import XPath
from io import StringIO

def test_CanReadFromStdin(monkeypatch):
    xpath = XPath()
    string = "<a></a>\n"
    monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', StringIO(string))
    assert xpath.readStdin() == string
```

However, this fails with

```
FAILED                               [100%]
TestXPath.py:4 (test_CanReadFromStdin)
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f2dafc5ec90>

    def test_CanReadFromStdin(monkeypatch):
        xpath = XPath()
        string = "<a></a>\n"
        monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', StringIO(string))
>       assert xpath.readStdin() == string

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
XPath.py:9: in readStdin
    return self.stdin.read()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

**pytest** was invoked without any flag. Adding the `-s` resulted in a never-ending loop. Interestingly, when I changed the line in *XPath.py* while omitting the constructor, to:

```py
    def readStdin(self):
        return sys.stdin.read()
```

the test ran successfully.

Why does the assignment in the constructor not work?

Comment: Because you are monkeypatching after `XPath` is created. Place the line `monkeypatch.setattr(...)` before `xpath = XPath()` to fix.

Comment: That was a good catch, I've put the monkeypatch on the top, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this solution. I'm using the `Mock()` from the library. Then I deleted the stdin assignment in the constructor.

```
#XPath.py
import sys
class XPath:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        pass

    def readStdin(self):
        return self.stream.read()


# test_file.py
import pytest
from XPath import XPath
from io import StringIO

def test_CanReadFromStdin(monkeypatch):
    string = "<a></a>\n"
    from unittest.mock import Mock
    mock_stdin = Mock()
    mock_stdin.readline = Mock(StringIO(string))
    monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', StringIO(string))
    import sys
    xpath = XPath(sys.stdin)
    assert xpath.readStdin() == string
```

**Update:** I included the stream (stdin) into the constructor again for demonstration purposes. That way I can write a second method and pass a file descriptor.